# POSTGRES) Dúvidas sobre o dump de blob's

Tags: postgresql

Estou com um impasse, mas até o momento, mesmo pesquisando bastante, não achei uma solução viável.

Em um servidor PostgreSQL9.6, estou tentando fazer o backup de um dos databases. Todavia, o mesmo possuí um volume grande de objetos grandes (blob's em sua maioria). Supondo que o banco tenha 100gb, 50gb são somente de blob's.

Gostaria portanto, de uma forma de fazer o backup do mesmo, sem estas estruturas.

Na documentação do pg_dump: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/app-pgdump.html encontrei o seguinte trecho:

---

**-b**

**--blobs**

Include large objects in the dump. This is the default behavior except when --schema, --table, or --schema-only is specified. The -b switch is therefore only useful to add large objects to dumps where a specific schema or table has been requested. Note that blobs are considered data and therefore will be included when --data-only is used, but not when --schema-only is.

Como posso realizar o backup sem os blob's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que você deveria consultar, na documentação, a opção seguinte:

```
-B
--no-blobs

    Exclude large objects in the dump.

    When both -b and -B are given, the behavior is to output large objects, when data is being dumped, see the -b documentation.
```